# How to read line from terminal and then pass it via exec command to another C++ program?

Tags: c++, shell, pipe, fork

I am writing a program in C++ which reads text from command line and then passes that to another program which uses this text.

Now, I am reading text in program 1 like so:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

And then I am using `forks` to open a child process and using `execl` command to run the executable of the program 2. Now I don't know how to make program 2 read this text and use it.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("Fork failed");
    exit(1);
}else if (pid == 0) {
    // Execute the rgen here after parent is done
    
    execl("./program2",".program2", NULL);

}
```

The above code works and runs the program 2. However, I just don't know how to pass the text read from terminal.

This is the full code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 std::string line;
 std::getline(std::cin, line);

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("Fork failed");
    exit(1);
}else if (pid == 0) {
    execl(".program2",".program2", NULL);

}


return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to open a pipe and send the data through it.

Comment: Hey paddy, 
I can't figure it out how to do it. And what do I need to change in program 2 for it to be able to read the data through pipe? Will I be sending the data via execl command that I am using above?